# Understanding 'sort by name' behavior in Finder

Tags: finder, sort

I don't understand the sort behavior I'm experiencing in Finder (MacOS Sierra). Is there anyway to get the 'sort by name' to sort alphabetically such that 0 < 9, a < z, and numbers < letters?

[image: Sorted by Name]

Comment: Have you tried sorting decreasing and then back to increasing in succession.  That worked for me.

Comment: Ya that didn't work for me.

Answer (score 5):

Apple OS X uses ["natural" sort order](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Natural_sort_order) in which a string of digits is considered as a unit.

The Apple documentation is in the Finder section of [this page](https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/FileManagement/Conceptual/FileSystemProgrammingGuide/FileSystemDetails/FileSystemDetails.html).

An old article on Finder sorting that may still be useful is [here](https://discussions.apple.com/docs/DOC-2084).

I think Terminal may sort the way you want.  There are also several 3rd party alternatives to the Finder which may offer that kind of sorting.

Comment: thanks! I added the answer below using the documentation link you provided.

Answer (score 2):

I was confused why `080c30.png` was coming after files that started with numbers greater than 0 (ex: `1c0f28.png`).

I followed the link to the documentation shared by Tom Gewecke above. It says:

> Substrings of digits are sorted according to their numeric value, as opposed to sorting the actual characters in the number.

In this case, the leading substring of digits in `080c30.png` is "80", which is greater than 1 (in `1c0f28.png`). There is no way to change the sort behavior for finder afaik, but yes you can sort the files in terminal or via 3rd party apps to get the behavior I was looking for.